# SFDX force:source:push fails only in CI environment

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org-definition-file, mdapi

I am trying to shift a hybrid codebase to SFDX. I'm using Gitlab CI running in the default gitlab-runners and for some reason I haven't been able to discover I keep having my code deploys failing. I am using the force:source:push command and everything works locally. I get 3 errors mostly, 'Invalid type: Schema.Network', 'Could not resolve standard field's name.', and 'Variable does not exist: MiddleName'. From what I understand most of these have to do with the scratch org definition file, but that doesn't explain why deploying locally works just fine. My scratch org def file is,

```
{
  "orgName": "Name",
  "edition": "Developer",
  "features": [
    "API",
    "Communities",
    "CustomNotificationType",
    "Knowledge",
    "ProcessBuilder",
    "ServiceCloud",
    "LightningServiceConsole",
    "LightningSalesConsole",
    "LiveAgent",
    "RecordTypes",
    "Sites",
    "SiteDotCom",
    "Workflow"
  ],
  "settings": {
    "lightningExperienceSettings": {
      "enableS1DesktopEnabled": true
    },
    "caseSettings": {
      "enableCaseFeed": true,
      "enableSuggestedSolutions": true,
      "showEmailAttachmentsInCaseAttachmentsRL": true,
      "useSystemEmailAddress": true
    },
    "communitiesSettings": {
      "enableNetworksEnabled": true
    },
    "nameSettings": {
      "enableMiddleName": true,
      "enableNameSuffix": true
    },
    "orderSettings": {
      "enableOrders": true
    },
    "ideasSettings": {
      "enableIdeas": true,
      "enableIdeasReputation": true
    },
    "orgPreferenceSettings":{
      "networksEnabled":true
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your scratch org definition appears to be correct. My hypothesis is that your CI system is not using it, or is using a different file.

> 'Invalid type: Schema.Network'

The features `Communities` and `Sites`, plus your `communitiesSettings`, make sure that your org has everything you need for Communities, including access to the Network entity.

> 'Could not resolve standard field's name.', and 'Variable does not exist: MiddleName'

I assume that these are referring to the same error. This would occur if the `nameSettings` you have specified here are not present.

You can safely remove

```
"orgPreferenceSettings":{
  "networksEnabled":true
}
```

which is now deprecated in favor of `communitiesSettings`.

Comment: Thanks for your help!